# How to loop through this nested object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a dynamically generated JavaScript object which consist of nested objects and arrays. I couldn't find a proper way to list all nested objects, since that particular object is created dynamically.

Here is the object:

```
var tagdata = {
  "Sentence": [{
      "NP": [{
          "NMP": "cat"
        }, {
          "NMP": "dog"
        }]
    }, {
      "VP": [{
          "KPD": "tree"
        }, {
          "NP": [{
              "NMP": "ball"
            }, {
              "NMP": "bat"
            }]
        },{
          "NP": [{
              "NMP": "ground"
            }, {
              "NMP": "time"
            }]
        }]
    }]
};
```

The output I require looks like this:

```
[{ key: 1, text: 'Sentence' },
 { key: 2, text: 'NP', parent: 1 },
 { key: 3, text: 'VP', parent: 1 },
 { key: 4, text: 'NMP', parent: 2 },
 { key: 5, text: 'NMP', parent: 2 },
 { key: 6, text: 'KPD', parent: 3 },
 { key: 7, text: 'NP', parent: 3 },
 { key: 8, text: 'NP', parent: 3 },
 { key: 9, text: 'cat', parent: 4 },
 { key: 10, text: 'dog', parent: 5 },
 { key: 11, text: 'tree', parent: 6 },
 { key: 12, text: 'NMP', parent: 7 },
 { key: 13, text: 'NMP', parent: 7 },
 { key: 14, text: 'NMP', parent: 8 },
 { key: 15, text: 'NMP', parent: 8 },
 { key: 16, text: 'ball', parent: 12},
 { key: 17, text: 'bat', parent: 13},
 { key: 18, text: 'ground', parent: 14},
 { key: 19, text: 'time', parent: 15},]
```

This data is to be used in a tree, so the order might be different, but the key:parent relationship should be maintained. Here is the code I've tried with:

```
let newtags=[{key:1,text:'Sentence'}];
tagdata["Sentence"].map( (elem,x) => {    
  newtags.push({key:x,text:Object.keys(elem)[0],parent:x});
  if(Object.keys(elem)[0].length !== 0){
    var y=x+1;
    newtags.push({key:y,text:Object.values(elem)[0][x],parent:y});
  }    
});

console.log(newtags);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for the first level, but in your attempt to go one level deeper you will assign duplicate *key* values (`y=x+1` when `x` will have that value in the next iteration of the `.map()` method as well).

What you need here is a recursive function, one that calls itself to deal with nested levels in the same way as any other level.

You could use this ES6, *functional programming* solution for that:

```js
function listItems(obj) {
    var key = 0;
    return (function recurse(obj, parent = undefined) {
        return Object(obj) !== obj ? { key: ++key, text: obj, parent }
            :   Array.isArray(obj) ? Object.keys(obj).reduce( (acc, text) =>
                    acc.concat(recurse(obj[text], parent)), [])
            :   Object.keys(obj).reduce( (acc, text) =>
                    acc.concat({ key: ++key, text, parent },
                                recurse(obj[text], key)), []);
    })(obj);
}

// Sample data
var tagdata = {
  "Sentence": [{
      "NP": [{ "NMP": "cat" }, { "NMP": "dog" }]
    }, {
      "VP": [{
          "KPD": "tree"
        }, {
          "NP": [{ "NMP": "ball" }, { "NMP": "bat" }]
        },{
          "NP": [{ "NMP": "ground" }, { "NMP": "time" }]
        }]
    }]
};

// Extract the objects and output:
console.log(listItems(tagdata));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm. btw ive added a new attribute to the json  like this
{ key: ++key, fill: blueA400, stroke: "#4d90fe",text: obj, parent }
since its created dynamically ive decided to call a function inside the json 
"fill:this.fillcolor(tagname)" but when i call the function like this it says fillcolor is not defined. any reason why im getting that?. the function works pretty well out side the json. this function is used to return a color depending on the name of the node

Comment: It is hard to say what goes wrong with your addition. As you can see, comments are not ideal for speaking about code. Make sure the context is indeed such that `this` is what you think it is. Don't hesitate to create a new question. If you want you can refer me to it, and I can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want. It uses a recursive algorithm that handles the case where you have an array separately from the case where you have an object. The base case of just a string is handled in `processChild`.

```js
let state = [];

function processChild(child, parent) {
  if (Array.isArray(child)) {
    return processArray(child, parent);
  }

  if (typeof(child) == 'object') {
    return processObject(child, parent);
  }

  let tag = {
    key: state.length + 1,
    text: child,
  };
  if (parent) {
    tag.parent = parent;
  }
  state.push(tag);
}

function processObject(object, parent) {
  parent = parent || 0;

  let keys = Object.keys(object);
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    //console.log(keys[i]);
    let tagIndex = state.length + 1;
    let text = keys[i];
    let tag = {
      key: tagIndex,
      text: text,
    };
    if (parent) {
      tag.parent = parent;
    }

    state.push(tag);

    let child = object[keys[i]];
    processChild(child, tagIndex);
  }
}

function processArray(array, parent) {
  parent = parent || 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    //console.log(array[i]);
    let child = array[i];
    //console.log('Child', child);
    processChild(child, parent);
  }
}

function process(){
  let initialState = JSON.parse(input.innerHTML);
  processChild(initialState);
  code.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(state).replace(/},/g,'},\n');
}
```

```css
#input{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input">
  {
  "Sentence": [{
    "NP": [{
      "NMP": "cat"
    }, {
      "NMP": "dog"
    }]
  }, {
    "VP": [{
      "KPD": "tree"
    }, {
      "NP": [{
        "NMP": "ball"
      }, {
        "NMP": "bat"
      }]
    }, {
      "NP": [{
        "NMP": "ground"
      }, {
        "NMP": "time"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
</textarea>
<button onClick="process()">Process</button>
<pre id="code"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a non-recursive approach.

- One array keeps track of the eventual results (`results`)
- One array keeps track of data-to-process
- When nested data is found, it is wrapped in a "to-do item" and added to the `todo` array
- Repeat until no items left

```js
var tagData = [{Sentence:[{NP:[{NMP:"cat"},{NMP:"dog"}]},{VP:[{KPD:"tree"},{NP:[{NMP:"ball"},{NMP:"bat"}]},{NP:[{NMP:"ground"},{NMP:"time"}]}]}]}];

var isNode = n => Array.isArray(n);
var isLeaf = n => !isNode(n);
var todoItem = parent => node => ({ parent, node });

var flatten = function(arr) {
  var result = [],
      todo = arr.map(todoItem(0)),
      current, node, parent, key, innerNode;

  while (todo.length) {
    ({node, parent} = todo.pop());
    key = result.length + 1;

    Object.keys(node).forEach(k => {
      innerNode = node[k];
      result.push({ key, parent, text: k });

      if (isLeaf(innerNode)) {
        result.push({ 
          key: key + 1,
          parent: key,
          text: innerNode
        });
      } else {
        todo = todo.concat(
          innerNode.map(todoItem(key)));
      }
    });
  };

  return result;
};

// Print output
console.log(
  flatten(tagData)
  .map(o => [
    "key: " + (o.key < 10 ? " " : "") + o.key,
    "parent: " + (o.parent < 10 ? " " : "") + o.parent,
    o.text
  ].join(" | "))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```